# kafka consumer request.timeout.ms meaning

Tags: apache-kafka

From https://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html#consumerconfigs, the entry for request.timeout.ms says:

> The configuration controls the maximum amount of time the client will wait for the response of a request. If the response is not received before the timeout elapses the client will resend the request if necessary or fail the request if retries are exhausted.

What kind of request/response are we talking about here?

Does this config affect the consumer leaving group or rebalancing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This affects requests like polling messages from consumer or any other requests that involve metadata of topic partitions.

Consumer would leave the group in case heartbeat was not received for more than `session.timeout.ms`, or in case consumer did not poll for over `max.poll.interval.ms`.

Comment: In which file I need to specify this? I am getting following error while ruining consumer group command

Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Aborted due to timeout.